# Play Framework 2.0 multiple checkboxes in JAVA via GET

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, checkbox

How do you handle multiple checkboxes in Play Framework 2.0 JAVA via GET?

The url looks similar to: `http://localhost:9000/games?type=platform&type=role`.
How can I get both "type" values in a "Set" variable in my controller?

My form looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="" value="all-types">
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="" value="platform">
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="" value="role">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms , section "Repeated Values":

1) Name the fields `type[0]`, `type[1]`, ....

2) You'll then have in the controller a List[String], out of which you have to look for the checked values.

Comment: Thanks Samuel! But that would require the whole controller to be written in Scala instead of Java?

Comment: As far as I could determine in http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms, the same in Java should work too.

Comment: Note:  playframework.org has been changed to playframewor.com.   Please update the above links and delete this message.